# Is there a way to create a trigger that will update an already existing view in mysql?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have created a view but I would like to create a trigger that will replace the view each time either of the 2 tables that are used to create the view are updated.

Is there a solution for this or any suggestions on how to accomplish the same goal? Another solution would be to run a MySQL script at specific intervals to replace the view but I don't see a way to do that in MySQL.

Any help would be appreciated.

Using PMA.

Comment: What change do you want to make to the view? Surely the view will be updated as the tables are.

Comment: You should read up on [materialized views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534506/how-to-implement-materialized-view-with-mysql)

Comment: Won't I need to refresh the view each time to reflect the new data?

Comment: It looks like you were correct Mike W...thanks for your help