# add column if there's exist table SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

i would to add this calculation:

```
select datepart(week, Order_date) as Weeks ,sum(Quantity) as Jumlah_Order 
from sales group by datepart(week, order_date);
```

to this table:

```
create table sales(Order_date date,Quantity int);
```

[image]

but i still not get it, because i query

```
ALTER TABLE sales
ADD datepart(week, Order_date) as Weeks ,sum(Quantity) as Jumlah_Order int
from sales group by datepart(week, order_date);
```

there's error message

Comment: Hi Tasya,
Your question is not very clear, could you please try to explain in a bit more detail what exactly it is that you are trying to do, and what is not working about it?

Comment: sorry for my bad explaining, but i just update my question about it

Comment: Calculated columns would require something like a `materialized View`  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534506/how-to-implement-materialized-view-with-mysql

Answer (score -1):

You cannot have calculated columns on a table. If you want to have a queryable dataset with calculated columns, you could consider looking into creating a 'view'

To add 'weeks' as a column, you could first add the column to your table, and then populate it with the datepart;

```
ALTER TABLE sales ADD Weeks int;
UPDATE sales SET Weeks = datepart(week, Order_date);
```

For the 2nd column, 'Quantity', it seems you want to populate an aggregated value (a SUM).
As you store data on row-level, but you want a grouped column (=SUM), that logically does not work.

Comment: hai thankyou for ur help, but there's still error around table on update table set. the error i get "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TABLE'"

Comment: TABLE should have been sales. I've modified my code.

Comment: I'd say that suggestion would break normalization 3NF https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40922009/sql-normalization-unl-1nf-2nf-3nf

Comment: Well yeah, as mentioned in my reply this should be considered as a view, not a table change.
But this is also showing how to add a column.